# Adjust Bootstrap NavBar position as per device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout where the logo and navbar are next to each other towards the left. When the viewport decreases, the nav bar comes under the logo and aligns left.

I am planning to keep the navbar to be on the right and center vertically aligned with the logo (currently navbar is top aligned). When the viewport size decreases, the navbar should come to the left under the logo.

I am trying this css, but the layout desired by me cannot be achieved

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        float: right;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        float:left;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqYJEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the navbar class from your nav (retain navbar-default)
2. Change col-md-9 to col-md-7 (or col-md-8) - you don't have a row parent so that adds padding
3. Add the following css

   ```
   @media (min-width: 768px) {
       .logoheader > * {
           display: inline-block;
           vertical-align: middle;
           float: none;
       }

       .navbar-default
       {
           float: right;
       }

       .navbar .navbar-collapse {
           float:left;
       }
   }
   ```